# Android: Adding image to button with shape background

Tags: android, button, android-activity, shapes

I'm new to android and writing my first app at the moment but I struggle with one thing for two days now: I have a button with shape from xml file as a background. Every button exept one will have text on it. The one with image is my headache - I used shape background and put the image in TextView: drawableTop but its size is different from every other button and I need all of them to be exactly the same size. Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonCoffee"
        style="@style/buttonText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/coffeepng"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="loadBreak"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
```

The style I am using for all of the buttons:

```
<style name="buttonText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_background_green</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop"> 5dp </item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp </item>
</style>
```

At the same time I'd like to ask few more question I came up while developing this app:

1. Is it more efficient to use shape as a button background or is it fine to use png image? Does it matter when it come to same size on different devices?
2. Is it ok to have many of activities or should I try to draw different sets of my buttons (depending on users style choice) on single activity?
3. How to pass an image from one activity to another?

Answer (score 1):

Create a shape in `drawable` folder named `button_shape.xml` as below...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ef4444" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#992f2f" />

    <corners android:radius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

Then use this shape to set as background of button as below...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1_2"
    style="@style/buttonText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="load1_2"
    android:text="@string/btn1_2"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/coffeepng"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape" />
```

Comment: Hi, I think I have include too many of the code and it could be confusing. I am doing exactly what you have told me to do but the problem is that on the top of the shape which is button background I want to include a png picture.

Comment: see my updated answer...use it...I think, you will get your result.

Comment: I use android:background="@drawable/button_shape" in styles for this button. The result I have is that the button is much taller than others.

Comment: cause, you have `android:drawableTop` in that button...remove it then it will not look as taller.

Comment: If I will remove android:drawableTop then how am I supouse to insert this png image?

Comment: Sorry for late reply...since you are using both text and image in one button and where image will be above the text...then its really tough to reduce the button height. Another fact, text size is also much higher. So, you can give an image preview how its look like now and how you want to see them.